# How to handle JWT token on client side of Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, authentication, jwt

There is Spring MVC application - the server produces HTML, the client is not SPA (i.e. this is not about API in any form).
During authentication JWT token is generated and returned to the client. During authorization the server verifies JWT token.

**How to store JWT token on client side and pass it via all further requests to the server?** Remember this is Spring MVC application and not SPA.

I tried to google for any examples but the only findings relate to REST authentication, that doesn't relate to this case at all.

In worst case we can perform authentication from JavaScript and store JWT token in cache/cookie. But maybe Spring MVC supports this out of the box and we need just to set some checkbox in configuration :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use "Set-Cookie" header with JWT token from server side. The client will interpret this header as setting a cookie automatically. In this case passing the token to every requests will be done without additional steps from client side.
Some details are described here https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

I will use this as an accepted answer until a better option provided.

Answer (score 2):

For non-SPAs, the usual approach is to store the authentication token in the server session. When the client makes a request, the appropriate session is retrieved via the JSESSIONID cookie (or the JSESSIONID is added to the URL if cookies are disabled).

I'm not sure why you can't use the approach above, but if you want to store the JWT on the client, a common approach is:

- store the token in the browser's local or session storage when it's generated, e.g. `window.sessionStorage.authToken = 'token_value'`;
- add the token to each subsequent request by setting the `Authorization` HTTP header to the value of the token
- when the user logs out, delete the token from browser storage

Comment: Do 3 steps you mentioned assume handling on JavaScript side? I'm interested if Spring MVC provides something for this. JavaScript way is pretty clear.

Comment: Regarding your first point about cookie based authentication, I would like not to have a state associated with a session, i.e. the client can connect to any server instance.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev yes, you would have to store/retrieve/delete the token using JavaScript